# visual studio webapi core has no Startup.cs

Tags: c#

Please someone should explain to me if you understand what exactly is going on... i am now using visual studio 2022 and have been battling for hours on how to implement server for my xamarin app(core api). i have tried many ways to create and re-create changing preferences but that doesnt seem to solve anything. it seems microsoft has taken out the startup.cs file from webapi core application.
as it stands now i dont know how to add services and i am planning on using mongoDB.
Someone please help me out..
is there a way i can go about this using visual studio 2022?
if i create the file, i can't add services without an error..

Comment: everything is in the program.cs class. Basically they have merged program.cs and startup.cs into one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: i am still a newbee so i don't know how to go about it. in the startup.cs, how do i end  the default app which comes with a view and then add my service